# Stress Analysis on a Bogie Frame Structure using ANSYS

Tags: ansys-apdl

The error is "*There is at least 1 small equation solver pivot term (e.g, at the UY degree of freedom of node 2144). Please check for an insufficiently constrained model*."

This error occurs while applying forces on a bogie frame structure in ANSYS mechanical APDL.

How can I correct this error? because the charged data is correct
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this type of error doesn't mean there is something "wrong" with node 2144. The finite element solver only discovers the error when it gets to the *last* node and degree of freedom that it processes, which just happens to be node 2144.

Most likely, there is something wrong with they way the model is constrained, and it can move as a rigid body.

Another reason for the problem might be that you created the mesh in several parts, and the parts are not properly connected together, so that one part can move freely relative to another part.

If you can't find the error by looking at the input, do a vibration analysis with the same constraints. You will probably find that the first mode has a frequency of 0 Hz, and the mode shape will show what the unwanted rigid body motion looks like. Then figure out how to restrain the model to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that node 2144 has a degree of freedom error at UY.